# Is the smallest solution always a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $\varphi(n)$ denote the totient function and let $k$ be a positive even integer.

Define $f(k)$ to be the smallest positive integer $n$ satisfying $$\varphi(n+k)-\varphi(n)=k$$

If for every even positive integer $k$ , there is a prime $p$ such that $p+k$ is prime as well , which is strongly conjectured , but not proven , then we always have a prime number as a solution.

> For $k\le 10^7$ , the smallest solution is always a prime number. If the above conjectre holds , can we assume that this is always the case ?

Comment: It seems to me that this problem, in a certain aspect, relates the sum and product of two numbers which are "independent" of each other. That's why it seems to me that solving this problem could be very difficult if not impossible.

Comment: New search limit : $$255\ 172\ 912$$ where the smallest solution is $1279$ , a "high water mark" or "jumping champion". No counterexample found.

Comment: And now $$532\ 932\ 016\ \ \   1423$$

Comment: Dear friend. You know, maybe better than me, that you can exhaust the potential of the best computer by always verifying your "No counterexample found" but that this is not a proof, that is, it is prohibited to extrapolate to a truth what is manifested with countless examples. It occurs to me (although perhaps the example is not very happy) that this would be analogue to ensuring that Collatz's conjecture is true because it is not possible at the moment to find an exception.

Comment: Please excuse me but I still think that the nature of your interesting problem makes a proof very difficult or even impossible. Best regards.

Comment: A great French mathematician once assured me at a conference in Bolivia that the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture is true. He knew that proof is not available at the moment but he was convinced of what he said knowing this lack. Perhaps you will be able to prove what your intuition supports. Hopefully so, which would be an extraordinary result when it comes to the always elusive prime numbers.

Comment: @Piquito I never claimed that this problem is easy , and I neither claim that we can solve it by extending the search limit. I do not understand the poitn of your comments. Currently , noone could deliver a reason why there is no reasonably small counterexample , so it is not stupid to continue the search. I hoped that the smallest composite solutions (if existent) would exhibit a structure , but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: All my respects to you and your love of mathematics.